# Files missing in cocoapod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an already developed code with 5 libraries added in pod target. Currently one of them is shown missing (in red) , but it is added to the pod spec file. How do I re-add the files ?

The error I am getting is -

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/admin/Downloads/App-name/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppName-FontAwesome+iOS/Pods-AppName-FontAwesome+iOS-prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Please help.

Comment: did you run `pod install` command?

Comment: yes..it is an already existing project..only the files are missing from source code and I am not sure I should re-add them on which path?

Comment: can you run pod install again and check. Sometimes it'll resolve the issue.

Comment: The file is missing in the code itself. :( I re-added it..but no use.

Comment: I had this problem as well whenever using cocoapods - did anyone find a solution?

Comment: I solved the problem by running "pod update" . It automatically installed the missing files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running "pod update" solved the problem for me.